# How do I get consistent results from an azure cloud function cosmos db query?

Tags: python, azure, function, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to use an azure python cloud function v2 to run a query against a cosmos db, and return the query as a json blob to a storage container. The problem is, I'm getting inconsistent results in the output.  The query should return c 4-5000 records, which i want to collate into a single json file.

How can I get a consistent result from the db for the query every time?

init.py looks like this:

```
import azure.functions as func
import json
import logging

def main(msgIn: func.QueueMessage, documents: func.DocumentList) -> str:
    if documents:
        logging.info('documents found in cosmosdb, saving to blob...')
        #serialize as a string to output to blob
        complete_docs_str = ','.join([doc.to_json() for doc in documents])
        complete_docs_str = "[" + complete_docs_str
        complete_docs_str = complete_docs_str + "]"
        logging.info('wrote to site.json blob in documents container')
        returnDoc = complete_docs_str
        return returnDoc
```

function.json looks like:

```
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
    {
        "name": "msgIn",
        "type": "queueTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "queueName": "documents-queue",
        "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    },
    {
        "type": "cosmosDB",
        "name": "documents",
        "direction": "in",
        "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
        "connectionStringSetting": "AzureCosmosDBConnectionString",
        "databaseName": "documentsdb",
        "collectionName": "documentscollection",
        "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.site = {site}",
    },
    {
        "name": "$return",
        "type": "blob",
        "direction": "out",
        "connection": "MyStorageConnectionString",
        "path": "documents/{site}.json"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are limits in terms of execution time etc. to Azure functions.
Are you sure your DB query has finished the execution before the function terminated and showed the results?
there is payload limit in functions as well.

refer link below for details:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#:~:text=A%20single%20function%20app%20only,at%20most%2C%20once%20per%20second](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#:%7E:text=A%20single%20function%20app%20only,at%20most%2C%20once%20per%20second).

other suggestion i have is to restrict the number of columns you are pulling to a small number and see if you get all rows.
as i suspect that it could either be size or execution time you are battling between.

Comment: thank you! you put me on the right track. I think i solved my problem by changin the partition key.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it seems that in my case, i was able to get consistent results by changing the collection partition key from /id to /site. The database has roughly 25k individual entries, all with unique ids. there are roughly 20 different values for /site across the collection.

My queries which sometimes look for up to 4000 results (select * from c where c.site = "foo"), now produce consistent results everytime.